# Question where sum of terms of an AP is a trignometric function

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic-progressions

The question is as such

If the sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic progression is denoted by $S_n$ and

$$S_n = 6n\sec^2 \theta + n(n-1)(\sin^2 \theta(4 + \tan^2 \theta) + \cos^2 \theta(4 + \cot^2 \theta))$$

where $\theta \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Then the minimum value of the common difference of the arithmetic progression is

(a) 10, (b) 12, (c) 14, or (d) 16,

could not find a similar question on google, I tried to break up the $4 + \tan^2 \theta$ and $4 + \cot^2 \theta$ in the brackets into $\sec^2 \theta + 3$ and $\csc^2 \theta + 3$ and then get somewhere however could not

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try $\theta = \pi/4$ in the second term. That is, you want to minimuze $S_{n+1}-2S_n+S_{n-1}$.

Comment: Doesn't $S_0$ need to be $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** For an arithmetic progression $a_i = k i + a_0$ (our aim is to minimize $k$), the sum of the first $n$ terms is
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (k i + a_0) = n (n - 1) \cdot \frac12 k + n \cdot a_0 .$$
So,
$$\frac12 k = \sin^2 \theta (4 + \tan^2 \theta) + \cos^2 \theta (4 + \cot^2 \theta). $$ In terms of $u := \sin^2 \theta$, which takes on precisely the values $(0, 1)$,
$$\frac12 k = 1 + \frac{1}{u (1 - u)}.$$